# HMM - state transition depending on amount of time spent in states

Tags: hidden-markov-model

Can we have a HMM where state transition is dependent on amount of time spent in states?

Suppose I build a hidden markov model(HMM) with 2 hidden states - S1, S2. In normal HMM, we assume the state transitions P(S1|S2) and P(S2|S1) is same irrespective of the time spent in S1 and S2.

Is there a way to relax this assumption? e.g. In my use case - a better assumption may be - Probability of transitioning to S2 from S1 i.e. P(S2|S1) at time t, is a decreasing function of how much time is spent in S1 till time t.

In other words, if more time is spent in a state, the probability of transitioning out of that state decreases. Is there a similar model in literature that I can use?

Comment: If you truly mean the transition probability at time $t$ can depend on the *total* time spent in a state from the inception through time $t,$ then the model does not have the Markov property, which might make it difficult to modify the HMM appropriately.  If you only mean the transition probability depends on the *current* amount of time in the state, and especially if the dependency stops changing after a small amount of residence time, then you can more readily make progress.  Which case are you interested in?

Comment: Am interested in 2nd case i.e. transition probability depends on the current amount of time in the state but I am not clear on what you mean by  - "if the dependency stops changing after a small amount of residence time"

Comment: One standard method to model Markov chains that "remember" a bounded number of steps in the past is to introduce states to keep track of that.  The simplest example is where the transition probability out of state S1 depends on whether you entered S1 on the previous step or have been there longer than one step.  Create a new state S1.1 and make S1 transition to S1.1 if it does not transition to S2 immediately.   Provided you only have to create a bounded number of states, you will still have a Markov process.

Comment: How will I ensure that conditional distribution of observations given hidden states is same for S1 and S1.1?

Comment: @tamalkuila How are you estimating the transition probabilities? With loglinear models? Implement constraints.

Comment: Expectation maximization(EM) algorithm. The formulation of EM is such that the constraints are taken care of automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of time a chain $X_t$ spends in some set or region $A$ up until time $k$ can be written as 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k 1(X_i \in A).
$$
Making the transitions at time $k$ depend on this would imply the process is no longer a Markov chain.

However, if you create a variable 
$$
\tilde{X}_k = \sum_{i=k-l+1}^k 1(X_i \in A)
$$
then this is Markov of order $l$, and this will be a Markov chain. You will have to manually derive the transitions of this chain, but in general, it can only go up one, down one, or stay the same.

And, as [@whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) points out, you may have the the transition matrix of the hidden chain depend on time *deterministically*. It is often assumed for convenience that the chain is homogeneous, but this is not necessary.

Third, you might be interested in [left-to-right hidden Markov models](https://paris.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/subakan-waspaa15.pdf). Instead of the hidden state representing which regime you're in, it will represent the amount of time heretofore spent in state, say, $1$. That means that this state can only increase, or stay the same, making the transition matrix upper-triangular (and very large).

Comment: Yes. I understand that the hidden state will not follow a markov chain. I am interested if there are any such generalization of HMM available which incorporates the assumptions that I stated in the question.